# add a int value to another int value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, addition

im making a game where you basically eat stuff and gain its mass and add it to your own.
im trying to set a new value and i havnt been able to figure out how and im not finding a working code
its basically this part thats the main issue:

```
void setNewMass()
 {
  currentMass + enemyMass
 }
```

both are int values

i just cant find what i need for that logic.
im attaching the whole script as well below.
i am new to coding. it was never a subject in school so im self teaching. sorry in advance
i am also having issues with "die" and "setNewMass" coming up as errors in the if statement.

gives error :

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0201)

i have searched the error but i genuinely struggled to understand what it meant.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class massLogic : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private bool collision;
        private int currentMass;
        public int enemyMass; 
        public Rigidbody2D rb2d;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
             currentMass = 1;
         
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if(collision)
            {
                if(currentMass <= enemyMass)
                {
                    die;
                } 
                if(currentMass > enemyMass)
                {
                 setNewMass;
                }
            
            
            }
            if(!collision)
                {
                    return;
                }
        }

         void die() 
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("total mass");
            }
    
         void setNewMass()
        {
          currentMass + enemyMass;
     
        }

    }
```

ive tried looking online but im not even sure how to search what i need. i have tried its just when you find info if your new its still 70% gibberish. ive tried searching "c# addint int together" "c# adding 2 values2 ive tried a few i honestly need a lil help

Comment: `setNewMass` doesn't set anything, as there isn't an equal sign

Comment: Try `currentMass = currentMass + enemyMass`, or better yet `currentMass += enemyMass`. The calculation result is currently returned to nothing.

Comment: `currentMass += enemyMass` is what you want. That is shorthand for `currentMass = currentMass + enemyMass`. Currently you are adding them together but not doing anything with the result

Comment: hey thanks foir fast reply i just added the = before set new mass its coming up a sytax error but no longer dosnt recognise it. not sure why because it looks correct

Comment: ah was that really it? lmao feel daft. lol . so the setNewMass at the bottoms  but im still having issues with the "die" and "setNewMas" in the if statements

Comment: Replace `die;` with `die();` - you need braces when callig a method. Btw. method names should be upper case, so change method signature to `void Die()` and call it with `Die();` (same for the other method..)

Comment: YES THANK YOU. stuff like this man. its such a basic fix but i had no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue with die is that you're not calling die(). To call a function, you need to write the functions name with the parameters at the end in brackets. If there are no parameters, then you just put ().

So on line 27 you need to put die();, not die;.

Same issue with setNewMass(). Make sure to include parenthesis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).